# Check server status in ruby using domain name?

Tags: ruby, boolean

I want to be able to survey a website and see if it is online. I would like it to return a boolean value, but i can't find out a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: What code did you write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @JacobRelkin yanked his answer, I'll post it. Note that you must include the protocol in the domain name.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def website_online?(site_url) 
   begin
      url = URI.parse(site_url)
      res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
        http.get('/')
      }
      res.body.length > 0
   rescue 
      false
   end
end

p website_online?( 'phrogz.net' )
#=> false

p website_online?( 'http://phrogz.net' )
#=> true
```

Comment: Hey!!! I had been testing my answer in irb and I had gotten some weird results, so I yanked it.

Comment: @JacobRelkin If you feel that it's worthwhile, by all means post it and I will summarily delete this answer and re-vote yours up. It appeared to be working in my tests so I didn't want the OP to go without a good answer. Absolutely no offence intended; I had wondered why you yanked yours.

Answer (score 0):

Varies what you mean by "online" and also if ping isn't disabled.

```
system('ping hostname')
```

You also get access to all of the built in system tools feedback.